# I want to retrieve filename for each file in a directory using for in shellscript..Below is the script i am applying

Tags: shell, ubuntu

But it is displaying the whole directory path instead of file name

```
PATH=/home/isrctn/Documents/*
for file in $PATH
do
echo $file
done
```

Comment: Also i am looking for deleting all files from that directory using above script

Comment: don't use `PATH` that is a reserved name! You'll really mess up your system. AND whynot just `cd $dir; rm *` ? Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

have a look at the man pages for `basename`

```
$ basename /foo/bar
bar
```

Try the following...

```
MY_PATH=/home/isrctn/Documents/*
for file in $MY_PATH
do
echo basename $file
rm $file
done
```

Comment: thanks man..the basename strips the directory name and suffix from file name. but for the same, but is  the above script is wrong

Comment: can you help me with  script for  removing all files in that directory..i tried "rm" command instead of "echo"..it throws error ..command not found

Comment: did you try rm $file or rm basename $file? You want to use the first. This assumes that they are files and not directories

Comment: what OS are you using? In terminal do you get a man page when you type 'man rm'

Comment: `command not found` for `rm` is because of the `PATH` variable name issue that shelter pointed out in the comments on the question.

Comment: ah, had assumed that they had changed the path!